# cannot add a child that doesn't have a yoganode to a parent

Tags: javascript, react-native

I m getting an error and I searched on it for a couple of hours but the only thing I found was there could be a syntax error in the code but I wasn't able to find any even after a lot of searching. I m not that experienced in coding just started learning react-native so anything you could suggest or point to would be really helpful. I m posting my code below. The error I m getting is :

> cannot add a child that doesn't have a yoganode to a parent without a measure function!(Trying to add a 'ReactRawTextShadowNode' to a 'LayoutShadowNode')

**React Native version: 0.52.0**

`import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';`

`class Dashboard extends React.Component {`

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] };
}

componentDidMount() {
    let listmount = this.state.list.map((listing => {
        return (
            console.log(listing.listmount, 'ls list'),
            <View key={listing.listmount}><Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{listing.listmount}</Text></View>
        );
    }));
    this.setState({ list: listmount });
    console.log(listmount, 'showing list');
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' }}>
            <View style={styles.dashboard}>{this.state.list}</View>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

`const styles = {
    dashboard: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
    itemViewStyle: {
        padding: 10,
        flex: 1,
        margin: 10,
        flexBasis: '40%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'blue',
    }
};`

`export default Dashboard;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
state = { list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] };

listRenderer() {
   return this.state.list.map(listing =>
        <View key={'view ' + listing}>
            <Text key={'text ' + listing } style={{ color: 'black' }}>
                {listing}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' }}>
            <View style={styles.dashboard}>{this.listRenderer()}</View>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Well this works for me just tried to return the main map function and a little code sorting did the job for me. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display list with `<View>`, it should be enclosed with `<Text>`

```
<View style={{ borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' }}>
        <Text style={styles.dashboard}>{this.state.list}</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: I tried your answer but {this.state.list} was evaluated as null when I ran the code. by the way, thanks for your help really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the list separately, you should create a method that returns the list, called in the **render** method of the component. For this component a better approach could be:

```
renderList() {
  return (

  <View style={styles.dashboard}>

  {
   this.state.list.map(
    listing => 
       <View key={listing.listmount}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'black' }}>{listing.listmount}</Text
       </View>
       );
    )
  }
  </View>
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' }}>
            {this.renderList()}
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Comment: well, still the same error  by the way I tried with {this.renderList()} was not able to run with just {renderList()}. Thanks a lot for the help really appreciate it. :)